# How can i prevent user from accessing the page using the link after logging out?

Tags: spring

After logging out i want the user to never access the page even if they know the correct url and type it in. IF they type in the url of a page which they see when they login, it should be redirected to home page.

I used the code in `header.jsp`file

```jsp
<core:if test="${userName == null}">
    <script>
         parent.location.href='logout.html'
    </script>
</core:if>
```

But since the header is included in both about us page and registration page i had to create a different header for those two files without including the above code.
Is there a better solution?

explanation

1. Login and Navigate to a Page in the URL. Copy the URL of the Page
2. Logout
3. In the same browser window, paste the URL

Site is running fine without seeking any login details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very sure about what you are asking, but here we go:
I assume you are protecting some private urls by means of spring security, for example:

```xml
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <!-- ...more configuration stuff -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/private/*" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
    <!-- ...more configuration stuff -->
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/yourUrlAfterLogout.html"/>
</security:http>
```

Then, when user logs out, he can't access private urls anymore.
(**UPDATE**: End of Spring Security part)

If you want to prevent user accessing these protected pages when he press back button in the navigator or copy the private url, you can configure [WebContentInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/WebContentInterceptor.html) as follows:

```xml
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="-1" />
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: I have not implemented spring-security on my project yet. What i need is people should not be able to access page after logging out and they should be able to see pages which they usually seen without logging in.

edited the question a little by adding an explanation. please check it.

Comment: But are you using spring mvc? because the second part of my answer has nothing to do with spring security, it's only spring mvc. Anyway, I will update and clarify.